# how to hold the image on screen while using bitmap android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have to display three images (dex5, dex6, dex7) using bitmap. When I run the following code the images displays on screen for milliseconds and this process does not end. 
Firstly how to hold each image for longer time (for like 1 second)????
secondly I want to continue this whole process (displaying each image for 1 second) for 30 seconds. how to stop this process based on time????

My code is:

```
public class DrawingTheImage extends View{

private Bitmap[] btm = new Bitmap[3];
int x , y;
Random rand = new Random();
int i;

public DrawingTheImage(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    btm[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dex5);
    btm[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dex6);
    btm[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dex7);
    x = 0;
    y = 250;

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDraw(canvas);
Random rand = new Random();
int i;
boolean j;
    i = rand.nextInt(3);

    if (j = rand.nextBoolean()){        
        canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 100, y, null);
    }else if (j = rand.nextBoolean()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 200, y, null);    
}else if(j = rand.nextBoolean()){
    canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 300, y, null);
    }
    invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onDraw is called many times a second, how often I dont know. That is half the reason you see flickering. The other half is your code

```
int i;
boolean j;
i = rand.nextInt(3);

if (j = rand.nextBoolean()){        
    canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 100, y, null);
}else if (j = rand.nextBoolean()) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 200, y, null);    
}else if(j = rand.nextBoolean()){
    canvas.drawBitmap(btm[i], 300, y, null);
}
```

This line

```
j = rand.nextBoolean()
```

you have an if else if statement with 3 of the same condition meaning either the first statement will execute or none will.

To do what you want to accomplish you need a timer of some sort and only change the image after the timer expires.

```
long timer = 0;
long delay = 30000;
Bitmap image = null;
public void changeImage(){

    if(delay < 0){
        //change image
        int i = rand.nextInt(3);
        image = btm[i];
        delay = 30000;
    }else{
        delay -= (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer);
    }

    timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Then in your onDraw method you only need

```
changeImage();
canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y,null);
```

Comment: I did what you said, but I am getting this error :  E/AndroidRuntime(946): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I fixed the above error. But the images are still displaying for milliseconds. How can I make them display on screen for longer time????

Comment: did you try iLate's answer? removing invalidate() from onDraw()?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is actually that there's a call to `invalidate()` in the onDraw method. Calling invalidate leads to a new drawing pass which will cause a new call to onDraw per se. So you're falling in an endless onDraw recursion. You need to remove this `invalidate()`. Also do not create new objects in the `onDraw` method. As **triggs** noted onDraw is called many times even without the endless recursion so you should avoid at all cost creating objects there.